# How should I do a count of docs for each related doc in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of tags, and for each tag I want to count the total number of documents (jobs) for that tag.

This works fine with a few tags and a few documents, but now I have over 100 tags and 200 documents, so the query to sum all the docs for each tag takes 10-15 seconds.

```
/**
 * Get tags
 */
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    Tag.find()
        .execQ()
        .then(function (tags) {
            utils.tag.getJobCountByTags(tags, user)
                .then(function(tagsWithCount){
                    res.json(tagsWithCount);
                });
        })
        .fail(function(err){
            res.send(err);
        });
};


//utils.tag namespace
tag.getJobCountByTags = function (tags, user){
    var queries = tags.map(function(tag){
        return getJobCountByTag(tag, user);
    });

    return q.all(queries);
};

function getJobCountByTag(tag, user){
    var Job = mongoose.model('Job');
    var whereData = {};
    var tagId = tag._id;

    if ( tag.type === 'skillTag' ) {
        whereData.skillTags = tagId;
    } else if ( tag.type === 'roleTag' ) {
        whereData.roleTags = tagId;
    }

    return Job
        .find(whereData)
        .execQ()
        .then(function (jobs) {
            tag._doc.count = jobs.length;

            return tag;
        });

}
```

This is the best I could come up with but its super slow to query all tags and for each tag query all documents by tag.

Edit: here is the Job schema...

```
/**
 * Job Schema
 */
var JobSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    location: { type: String, required: true },
    geoLocation: { type: [Number], index: '2d' },
    company: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    skillTags: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag', index: true, required: true }],
    roleTags: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag', index: true, required: true }]
}, {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

Comment: I added the Job schema.

Comment: I've provided an answer below but your Job schema doesn't seem to have the `locationTags` field defined so the aggregation framework will have the `count` for that tag type as 0 if the `Job` model doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks I'm actually not using location tags yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the aggregation framework to get the desired result. The following aggregation pipeline has the first stage as the **[`$uwnind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator to deconstruct the array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element. You can then use **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator to group the input documents from the previous **[`$uwnind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** pipeline by the tag type identifier expression and applies the accumulator expression [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) to each group to get the count:

```
function getJobCountByTag(tag){
    var Job  = mongoose.model('Job', jobSchema);,
        tagType = "$"+tag.type+"s",
        pipeline = [
            { "$unwind": tagType },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": tagType,
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                 }
            }
        ];

    return Job
        .aggregate(pipeline)
        .execQ()
        .then(function (res) {
            tag._doc.count = res.count;

            return tag;
        });
}
```

or using the aggregation pipeline builder fluent API

```
function getJobCountByTag(tag){
    var Job = mongoose.model('Job'),
        tagType = "$"+tag.type+"s",

    return Job
        .aggregate()
        .unwind(tag.type+"s")
        .group({
            "_id": tagType,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        })
        .execQ()
        .then(function (res) {
            tag._doc.count = res.count;

            return tag;
        });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put a conditional into the jobs query? I only want to get jobs that have a matching tag id.